# Print UTF-8 string in ICU

Tags: c, string, encoding, utf-8, icu

I recently discovered ICU's `ustdio.h` and thought it would be fun to test. It didn't take long to see that something wasn't quite right.

Python 3 supports UTF-8 in its string literals, so a statement like

```
print("90°")
```

is valid.

ICU (in the C API) provides `u_printf()` and `u_printf_u()`, the latter of which is designed for whatever `UChar` is on the system's implementation, but is at least UTF-16.

In attempt to test, I tried printing out a special character, the degree symbol.

```
u_printf("90%c\n", 0xB0);
```

printed `90�`, as did the following:

```
u_printf(u8"90%c\n", 0xB0);
u_printf("90°\n");
u_printf(u8"90°\n");
u_printf_u(u"90%c\n", 0x00B0);
```

However, actually declaring that character in a UTF-16 string literal got the desired result.

```
u_printf_u(u"90°\n");

$ ./a.out
90°
```

I could stick with this, but I want UTF-8 compliance; it seems to be a superior system. Why aren't the UTF-8 string literals from C11 compatible with ICU's `u_printf()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to navigate the issue by creating a string literal with Unicode characters in it and passing it as a `char *` argument to `printf()`.

The following code prints the line `José 90°\n` four times.

```
char *s = u8"José 90°";
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); ++i)
    putchar(s[i]);
putchar('\n');
printf("%s\n", s);
u_printf("%s\n", s);

UErrorCode error = U_ZERO_ERROR;
u_init(&error);
UChar *s16 = malloc(256*sizeof(UChar));
u_strFromUTF8(s16, 256, NULL, s, strlen(s), &error);
u_printf_u(u"%S\n", s16);

free(s16);
```

The buffer `s16` can be used with `u_strToUTF8()` to go back successfully and be compatible with UTF-8 functions. Internal things in ICU appear to prefer UTF-16 (I guess it's easier to parse), so you'll need to convert to it before converting back to UTF-8 to return to the caller.